# CSS Table Borders

Tags: css, html-table

A table has the following attributes and associated CSS:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="noborder">
```

> .noborder {  border: 0px; }

Yet it displays with a white border of 1px.  Google Chrome Inspector shows there is an associated style in a "user agent stylesheet", with CSS of:

> table { display: table; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing:
>   2px; border-color: gray; }

but this is not a white border.  What CSS is generating the white border?

Comment: I thought this was a website design issue, rather than a server issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This CSS rule in your `style.css` is making the border

```
th,td {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 8px;
}
```